# how to write a test script using Javascript/Protractor for mouse over and click from menu displayed

Tags: javascript, protractor

Here is the html code for the mouse over. I want to be able to write a script using javascript to hover over "Product & Services" and then click on isentia.mediaportal

Please help as this is for my interview
Thanks

```
<li class="first-item has-children dropdown products first">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle root-menu">Products &amp; Services</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="first-item has-children dropdown all-products">
            <a href="#" class="">Products</a>
            <ul class="">
                <li class="first-item has-children">
                    <a title="isentia.mediaportal" href="/tools/mediaportal" class="">isentia.mediaportal</a>
                    <ul class="">
                        <li class="first-item menu_blurb"><span>Our Suite of Media Monitoring Tools: All your PR &amp; Analytics in one platform</span></li>
```

I have created this bit of spec.js

```
    // spec.js
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://www.isentia.com/');

    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Products & Services');

    var dropdown-toggle = element(by.id('dropdown-toggle'));
    expect(dropdown-toggle.getText()).toEqual('Products & Services');

     it('should have a title', function() {
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('isentia.mediaportal');
  }); 
 element(by.css('a[href*="/tools/mediaportal"]'))

  });
 });
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. StackOverflow is not a "code-for-me" website.

Comment: I have done a bit of coding but i am new to this, not sure if this would work.

Comment: Thanks. @SeanFrancisN.Ballais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `browser.actions()` to perform mouse actions on any webelement. try the below code.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var productsAndServiceMenu = element(by.linkText("Products &amp; Services"));
var subMenu = element(by.linkText("isentia.mediaportal"));
browser.actions().mouseMove(productsAndServiceMenu).perform();
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(subMenu),5000);
subMenu.click();
```

Refer [http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions](http://protractor%20actions)

Comment: Hi the test seems to run without any failure, but the execution is so quick that i cant add see if the navigation part. Could someone please tell me how to slow down the navigation. So far my code spec.js file is as below:

Comment: browser.get('http://www.isentia.com/');

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var productsAndServiceMenu = element(by.linkText("Products &amp; Services"));
var subMenu = element(by.linkText("isentia.mediaportal"));
browser.actions().mouseMove(productsAndServiceMenu).perform();
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(subMenu),15000);
subMenu.click();

browser.driver.sleep(15000);
browser.waitForAngular();